# unable to verify mobile app on IOS9 using Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have been trying to take advantage of Xcode now allowing developers to test on devices without being enrolled on the developer program.

This was working just a few weeks ago, no problems at all

however, for no apparent reason, I am getting this error message whenever i try to run my app on the iPhone:

[image]

after some googling a website led me to this page in the settings app:

[image]

From what i can gather on google, The problem is that the app isn't verified. However when i click verify nothing changes. The text at the top of the screen changes very briefly (i assume it's saying loading)

I have tried deleting the provisioning profile, that Xcode had created, and clicking fix when Xcode tells me it can't find the profile. Nothing changed

so my question is: does anybody know what the problem is here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a problem with that before but with x-code there are usually 3 really annoying but normally foolproof steps to solving a problem such as this.

1) Update your IOS and make sure you are on the most recent version

2) Reinstall X-code

3) Recreate the app

Like I said those 3 steps can normally solve any non code related problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: an hr to download Xcode... company networks suck -_-......... anyway this did not help unfortunately, I deleted the project and rebuilt it (it's a phone gap project), reinstalled Xcode and IOS9 is up to date -- same problem